# How to read mutliline input from stdin into variable and how to print one out in shell(sh,bash)?

Tags: bash, shell, stdin, multiline

What I want to do is the following:

1. read in multiple line input from `stdin` into variable `A`
2. make various operations on `A`
3. pipe `A` without losing delimiter symbols (`\n`,`\r`,`\t`,etc) to another command

The current problem is that, I can't read it in with `read` command, because it stops reading at newline.

I can read stdin with `cat`, like this:

```
my_var=`cat /dev/stdin`
```

, but then I don't know how to print it. So that the newline, tab, and other delimiters are still there.

My sample script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

A=`cat /dev/stdin`

if [ ${#A} -eq 0 ]; then
        exit 0
else
        cat ${A} | /usr/local/sbin/nextcommand
fi
```

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This is working for me:

```
myvar=`cat`

echo "$myvar"
```

The quotes around `$myvar` are important.

Comment: Should read myvar=$(cat); echo "${myvar}" -- but otherwise my solution exactly.

Comment: gnud, those extra quote characters you suggest don't actually change the functionality.

Comment: @appenwarr: quotes are vital, otherwise youre relying in IFS being at default value, which is a very bad practice.

Comment: Fails. `echo "$myvar"` adds a newline to the file if it did not previously have one.

Comment: @CommaToast, that's a function of the echo, not the quotes.  Use the `-n` flag (or equivalent on your platform).  The echo was simply an example of usage.

Comment: Erm.. This removes trailing LFs from the stdin.

Comment: To keep newlines, use `var=$(cat; echo -ne '\r'); var=${var%\r}`

Comment: Note that bash can't store null characters in variables, thus in case stdin contains null characters (my case), this won't work! See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570531/assign-string-containing-null-character-0-to-a-variable-in-bash

Answer (score 35):

In Bash, there's an alternative way; `man bash` mentions:

> The command substitution `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`.

```
$ myVar=$(</dev/stdin)
hello
this is test
$ echo "$myVar"
hello
this is test
```

Comment: -1 because `echo "$myVar"` will add a newline character if it did not already have one.

Comment: @CommaToast: And `$(...)` will remove any trailing newlines, so they fit perfectly together, don't they? And you can easily switch to `printf` to avoid that.

Comment: No, they don't fit together perfectly. You will end up with a trailing newline no matter what in this solution, whether or not there was one to begin with. If you switch to printf arbitrarily, now you will never have a trailing newline, even if there was one.

Comment: @CommaToast: I agree that the behavior of `$(...)` isn't optimal. But there are ways around that, see [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst#examples)

Comment: Well to be fair it's not your fault that unix was designed in 1946 and is basically a glorified typewriter, as far as it's concerned. I can just see the carriage return going back and forth inside unix's brain. It just can't be asked to treat newlines like every other character. No, it just *has* to revert to its typewriter reptilian brain. But anyway the only workaround I could find to this is `var=\`cat; echo x\`` then later when ready to output it, output `${var%x}` so that newlines (or lack thereof) are preserved. Ugly as heck but, it works...

Comment: @CommaToast: Right. I've added this as an additional answer, for those cases where trailing newlines (or lack thereof) must be preserved.

Comment: Nods. I want to make a version of Unix that has a completely separate character set for commands and programming compared to the character set used for comments and content. There'd be a second caps-lock button that would be "command-lock" and it would be cruise-control for win. That way, for example, a newline in the *command* set could always be respected, whereas a newline in the *content* would be ignored in situations like this. Of course, documents would need to be able to be switched so their command characters were made into content for purposes like git.

Comment: @IngoKarkat How to stop after multiline input? If I press Ctrl C it stops but the variable is not saved!

Comment: @Nikhil The Ctrl-C aborts your entire script; it's difficult to forward it to the subcommand. To skip reading input after N lines, I would use `head`: `myVar=$(head -n 10 /dev/stdin)` If that doesn't suit you, you probably need to implement a `read`-loop yourself.

Comment: @Nikhil - use Ctrl-D instead of Ctrl-C to terminate input of a multi-line string here.

Comment: Note that bash can't store null characters in variables, thus in case stdin contains null characters (my case), this won't work!

Answer (score 13):

**tee** does the job

```
#!/bin/bash
myVar=$(tee)
```

Comment: +1 because tee is elegant and it works to read it in. Wow thanks! But you don't answer the question, how to print it with altering newlines.

Answer (score 13):

### [updated]

This assignment will hang indefinitely if there is nothing in the pipe...

```
var="$(< /dev/stdin)"
```

We can prevent this though by doing a timeout `read` for the first character. If it times out, the return code will be greater than 128 and we'll know the STDIN pipe (a.k.a `/dev/stdin`) is empty.

Otherwise, we get the rest of STDIN by...

- setting `IFS` to NULL for just the `read` command
- turning off escapes with `-r`
- eliminating read's delimiter with `-d ''`.
- and finally, appending that to the character we got initially

Thus...

```
__=""
_stdin=""

read -N1 -t1 __  && {
  (( $? <= 128 ))  && {
    IFS= read -rd '' _stdin
    _stdin="$__$_stdin"
  }
}
```

This technique avoids using `var="$(command ...)"` Command Substitution which, by design, will always strip off any trailing newlines.

If Command Substitution is preferred, to preserve trailing newlines we can append one or more delimiter characters to the output inside the `$()` and then strip them off outside.

For example *( note `$(parens)` in first command and `${braces}` in second )*...

```
_stdin="$(awk '{print}; END {print "|||"}' /dev/stdin)"
_stdin="${_stdin%|||}"
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes it works for me too. Thanks.

```
myvar=`cat`
```

is the same as

```
myvar=`cat /dev/stdin`
```

Well yes. From the `bash` man page:

> Enclosing  characters in double quotes
>   preserves the literal value of all
>   characters within the quotes,
>   with the exception of $, `, \, and, when history expansion is
>   enabled, !. The  characters  $  and `
>   retain their special meaning within double quotes.

Answer (score 7):

If you do care about preserving trailing newlines at the end of the output, use this:

```
myVar=$(cat; echo x)
myVar=${myVar%x}
printf %s "$myVar"
```

This uses the trick from [here](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst#examples).

Comment: Nice.  The last two lines can be replaced with just `echo -n "${myVar%x}"`  But fixing the variable first is more *modular* I guess.

Answer (score 3):

Read can also be used setting option -d [DELIMITER], in which `input' DELIMITER is one character long. If you set `-read d ''` then it reads until null or all input.

Just remember Bash cannot hold null bytes in variables, anyways.

```sh
read -d'' myvar
echo "$myvar"
```

Obs: trailing newline bytes are not preserved, though..

Comment: I'm using `-r` for `read`. i.e.:  `trim() { read -r str; str=${str##+([[:space:]])}; str=${str%%+([[:space:]])}; echo -n "${str}"; }`, and it works as : `$ echo "-$(echo ' a   b   ' | trim)-"` ⇢ `-a   b-`