# Reading null delimited strings through a Bash loop

Tags: bash, delimiter, null-character

I want to iterate through a list of files without caring about what characters the filenames might contain, so I use a list delimited by null characters. The code will explain things better.

```
# Set IFS to the null character to hopefully change the for..in
# delimiter from the space character (sadly does not appear to work).
IFS=$'\0'

# Get null delimited list of files
filelist="`find /some/path -type f -print0`"

# Iterate through list of files
for file in $filelist ; do
    # Arbitrary operations on $file here
done
```

The following code works when reading from a file, but I need to read from a variable containing text.

```
while read -d $'\0' line ; do
    # Code here
done < /path/to/inputfile
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to store null characters in a bash variable.  At least, I've never found a way to do it...

Comment: Confirmed, `bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input`. This is because bash is intended for posix derivative environments, in which env vars are internally stored in a null-terminated buffer, and bash vars are (in every case I've ever examined) host env vars.

Comment: You may be able to store a null char in a bash variable, but you can not get it out, so there is no way to tell. First example prove that assigning non-displayable chars works (as we all know), e.g. a tab in octal : `test=$'a\011b';echo ${#test} ="${test}"=` results in `3 =a b=`. Then try an octal 0 : `test=$'a\0b';echo ${#test} ="${test}"=` results in `1 =a=`; this reports the zero-terminated string length of $test as 1, but the 'b' and another zero may still be stored into the variable, we do not know.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The preferred way to do this is using process substitution:

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file <&3; do
    # Arbitrary operations on "$file" here
done 3< <(find /some/path -type f -print0)
```

If you were hell-bent on parsing a bash variable in a similar manner, you can do so *as long as the list is **not** NUL-terminated*.

Here is an example of bash var holding a tab-delimited string:

```
$ var="$(echo -ne 'foo\tbar\tbaz\t')"
$ while IFS= read -r -d $'\t' line <&3; do
    echo "#$line#"
  done 3<<<"$var"
#foo#
#bar#
#baz#
```

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I ended up using your second example.

Comment: What is the use of the IFS since the -d flag is set?

Comment: @thisirs By setting `IFS` to the null string, leading and trailing whitespace characters will be preserved.

Comment: Will "inlining" the `IFS` declaration behave differently than if it was in a separate line? Specifically, will it "scope it", so that after the `read` command, `IFS` will be set back to whatever it was?

Comment: @CamiloMartin exactly.  If there is no `;` after the variable assignment then its value will only apply to the command it prefixes, namely `read`.  You can prove this to yourself by running something like this `IFS=$'\t'; while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do od -c <<<"$IFS"; done < <(echo -e 'foo\0')` and note that IFS is still set to a tab inside the loop.

Comment: Does this actually work when using the here string syntax (`<<<`) as in the first example? In my tests only the process substitution works (`< <(...)`):
`while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do echo "$f"; done <<< "$(find Documents -print0)"` produces no output while `while IFS= read -d '' f; do echo "$f"; done < <(find Documents -print0)` lists the files in Documents.

Comment: Fully agree with @joanpau. I don't know how stuff worked in 2011, but in 2016 with bash4 this method does not work. You can easily verify that this fails it if you assign `var=$(find . -print0)` prior to while loop. Process substitution works indeed, but variables not. Even if you built a variable on the fly like `var=$(echo -e "some\0text")` will fail to separate `some` from `text`. For variables you need to make a trick like this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570531/assign-string-containing-null-character-0-to-a-variable-in-bash

Comment: This is not setting IFS to the null string. It is [unsetting IFS, causing it to use the default values ($' \t\n')](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/IFS).

Comment: Even if you could get nulls into an env var, you would still be limited to the maximum size of env vars (see xarg docs). By using a pipe or other redirection, not only can you move an unlimited(*) amount of data, but the two procedures can run in parallel; each process will wait for the others as needed. *"unlimited" irrespective of time of operation and other environmental conditions.

Comment: @jeremysprofile actually, `IFS=` is *disabling* word-splitting.  It is *not* setting IFS back to its default value like `unset IFS` does.

Comment: `echo -en ' x \0' | while read -r -d ''; do echo "<$REPLY>"; done`
prints `< x >` in bash3 and bash5 — demonstrating an undocumented `read -d` feature.

Comment: The `read -d ''` is documented to split on NUL characters for GNU bash: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read

Answer (score 6):

Pipe them to `xargs -0`:

`files="$( find ./ -iname 'file*' -print0 | xargs -0 )"`

[xargs manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html):

> ```
> -0, --null
>     Input items are terminated by a null character instead of
>     by whitespace, and the quotes and backslash are not
>     special (every character is taken literally).
> ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Use `env -0` to output the assignments by the zero byte.

```
env -0 | while IFS='' read -d '' line ; do
    var=${line%%=*}
    value=${line#*=}
    echo "Variable '$var' has the value '$value'"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of readability and maintainability a bash function might be cleaner:

An example that converts `MOV` files to `MP4` using `ffmpeg` (works with files containing spaces and special characters):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

do_convert () { 
  new_file="${1/.mov/.mp4}"
  ffmpeg -i "$1" "$new_file" && rm "$1" 
}

export -f do_convert  # needed to make the function visible inside xargs

find . -iname '*.mov' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} bash -c 'do_convert "{}"' _ {}
```

Does not apply to the OP's question but in case your input is generated by `find` then there is no need to pipe via `xargs -0` as `find` is perfectly capable of handling non-ascii characters and spaces in file names. If you don't care about readability and maintainability then the command above can be simplified to:

```sh
find . -type f -iname "*.mov" -exec bash -c 'ffmpeg -i "${1}" "${1%.*}.mp4" && rm "${1}"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: As noted in this answer, it doesn't handle arbitrary strings with null characters.  However, it does answer a different, common question for performing actions on files without using the "-print0 | xargs -0" form, and without using IFS= overrides.

Answer (score -6):

I tried working with the bash examples above, and finally gave up, and used Python, which worked the first time.  For me it turned out the problem was simpler outside the shell.  I know this is possibly off topic of a bash solution, but I'm posting it here anyway in case others want an alternative.

```
import sh
import path
files = path.Path(".").files()
for x in files:
    sh.cp("--reflink=always", x, "UUU00::%s"%(x.basename(),))
    sh.cp("--reflink=always", x, "UUU01::%s"%(x.basename(),))
```

Comment: Had a similar issue with a  (sh-, not bash-) shell script. Decided to rewrite that whole damn script in Perl.