# How can I search for files in directories that contain spaces in names, using "find"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, find

How can I search for files in directories that contain spaces in names, using `find`?
i use script

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `find "/tmp/1/" -iname "*.txt" | sed 's/[0-9A-Za-z]*\.txt//g'`
do
    for j in `ls "$i" | grep sh | sed 's/\.txt//g'`
    do
        find "/tmp/2/" -iname "$j.sh" -exec cp {} "$i" \;
    done
done
```

but the files and directories that contain spaces in names are not processed?

Comment: The problem is not really with `find` but with the `for` loops since "spaces" are taken as delimiter between items.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: @skamazin I have a .txt file in some directory. I want the script to search for files with the same name as that .txt file and copy them to the directory with the .txt file.
And i need recursive search.

Comment: @SerjAntiquity _"I want the script to search for files with the same name as that .txt file and copy them to the directory with the .txt file."_ If you copy a file with the _same name_ (incl. `.txt` ext.) you will overwrite it. Is that expected behavior?

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux, No, I copy a file with the same name, but with a different extension (.sh)

Comment: @SerjAntiquity As of now, you have several answers trying to fix your probably sub-optimal solution. May I suggest you to rephrase what you have explaned in your previous comments, and then edit you question (or even post an other question) -- focusing on _what you are trying to do_.

Comment: @Sylvain Lerou
Thx. ask a new question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash : iterate over list of files with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039130/bash-iterate-over-list-of-files-with-spaces)

Answer (score 6):

This will grab all the files that have spaces in them

```
$ls
more space  nospace  stillnospace  this is space
$find -type f -name "* *"
./this is space
./more space
```

Comment: The filter only for regular file types is missing. The directory-type files will not be filtered in you example.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to achieve you *goal*. But given your *actual solution*, the problem is not really with `find` but with the `for` loops since "spaces" are taken as delimiter between items.

`find` has a useful option for those cases:

> <sub>*from `man find`:*</sub>
>
> **-print0**
>
> True; print the full file name on the standard output, followed by a null character
>       (instead of the newline character that -print uses).  This allows file names
>     that contain newlines or other types of white space to be  correctly  interpreted
>     by  programs  that  process  the  find output.  This option corresponds to the -0
>     option of xargs.

As the man saids, this will match with the `-0` option of `xargs`. Several other standard tools have the equivalent option. You probably have to rewrite your complex pipeline around those tools in order to process cleanly file names containing spaces.

In addition, see [bash "for in" looping on null delimited string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677546/bash-for-in-looping-on-null-delimited-string-variable) to learn how to use *for loop* with 0-terminated arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

`find . -type f -name "* *"`

Instead of `.` you can specify your path, where you want to find files with your criteria

Answer (score 0):

Your first for loop is:

```
for i in `find "/tmp/1" -iname "*.txt" | sed 's/[0-9A-Za-z]*\.txt//g'`
```

If I understand it correctly, it is looking for all text files in the `/tmp/1` directory, and then attempting to remove the file name with the `sed` command right?  This would cause a single directory with multiple `.txt` files to be processed by the inner for loop more than once.  Is that what you want?

Instead of using sed to get rid of the filename, you can use `dirname` instead.  Also, later on, you use sed to get rid of the extension.  You can use `basename` for that.

```
for i in `find "/tmp/1" -iname "*.txt"` ; do
  path=$(dirname "$i")
  for j in `ls $path | grep POD` ; do
    file=$(basename "$j" .txt)
    # Do what ever you want with the file
```

This doesn't solve the problem of having a single directory processed multiple times, but if it is an issue for you, you can use the for loop above to store the file name in an array instead and then remove duplicates with `sort` and `uniq`.

Comment: I want the script to search for files with the same name as .txt and copy them to the directory in which the source is .txt

Answer (score 0):

Use `while read` loop with null-delimited pathname output from `find`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -rd '' i; do
    while IFS= read -rd '' j; do
        find "/tmp/2/" -iname "$j.sh" -exec echo cp '{}' "$i" \;
    done <(exec find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name '*POD*' -not -name '*.txt' -printf '%f\0')
done <(exec find /tmp/1 -iname '*.txt' -not -iname '[0-9A-Za-z]*.txt' -print0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never used `for i in $(find...)` or similar as it'll fail for file names containing white space as you saw.

Use `find ... | while IFS= read -r i` instead.

It's hard to say without sample input and expected output but something like this might be what you need:

```
find "/tmp/1/" -iname "*.txt" |
while IFS= read -r i
do
    i="${i%%[0-9A-Za-z]*\.txt}"
    for j in "$i"/*sh*
    do
        j="${j%%\.txt}"
        find "/tmp/2/" -iname "$j.sh" -exec cp {} "$i" \;
    done
done
```

The above will still fail for file names that contains newlines. If you have that situation and can't fix the file names then look into the `-print0` option for `find`, and piping it to `xargs -0`.