# Is there an option to "ls" that limits filename characters?

Tags: linux, unix

syntax question. if I have a number of subdirectories within a target dir, and I want to output the names of the subs to a text file I can easily run:

```
ls > filelist.txt
```

on the target. But say all of my subs are named with a 7 character prefix like:

```
JR-5426_mydir
JR-5487_mydir2
JR-5517_mydir3
...
```

and I just want the prefixes. Is there an option to "ls" that will only output n characters per line?

Comment: Have you tried [`cut(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut)?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ls` for progammatic use anyhow. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: If you want to be really safe from strange filename characters check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677546/bash-for-in-looping-on-null-delimited-string-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you use the `cut` command:

```
ls | cut -c1-7
```

Comment: I recommend `printf '%s\n' *` instead of `ls`

Comment: thank you. this takes care of my immediate need. will definitely study the other information provided as well.

Comment: Might need to [`sort -u`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/sort.html) the result once suffixes are trimmed.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `ls` in any programmatic context; it should be used strictly for presentation to humans -- [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) gives details on why.

On bash 4.0 or later, the below will provide a deduplicated list of filename prefixes:

```
declare -A prefixes_seen=( )     # create an associative array -- aka "hash" or "map"
for file in *; do                # iterate over all non-hidden directory entries
  prefixes_seen[${file:0:2}]=1   # add the first two chars of each as a key in the map
done
printf '%s\n' "${!prefixes_seen[@]}" # print all keys in the map separated by newlines
```

That said, if instead of wanting a 2-character prefix you want everything before the first `-`, you can write something cleaner:

```
declare -A prefixes_seen=( )
for file in *-*; do
  prefixes_seen[${file%%-*}]=1   # "${file%%-*}" cuts off "$file" at the first dash
done
printf '%s\n' "${!prefixes_seen[@]}"
```

...and if you don't care about deduplication:

```
for file in *-*; do
  printf '%s\n' "${file%%-*}"
done
```

...or, sticking with the two-character rule:

```
for file in *; do
  printf '%s\n' "${file:0:2}"
done
```

---

That said -- if you're trying to Do It Right, you shouldn't be using newlines to separate lists of filename characters either, because newlines are valid inside filenames on POSIX filesystems. Think about a file named `f$'\n'oobar` -- that is, with a literal newline in the second character; code written carelessly would see `f` as one prefix and `oo` as a second one, from this single name. Iterating over associative-array prefixes, as done for the deduplicating answers, is safer in this case, because it doesn't rely on any delimiter character.

To demonstrate the difference -- if instead of writing

```
printf '%s\n' "${!prefixes_seen[@]}"
```

you wrote

```
printf '%q\n' "${!prefixes_seen[@]}"
```

it would emit the prefix of the hypothetical file `f$'\n'oobar` as

```
$'f\n'
```

instead of

```
f
```

...with an extra newline below it.

---

If you want to pass lists of filenames (or, as here, filename prefixes) between programs, the safe way to do it is to NUL-delimit the elements -- as NULs are the single character which can't possibly exist in a valid UNIX path. (A filename also can't contain `/`, but a path obviously can).

A NUL-delimited list can be written like so:

```
printf '%s\0' "${!prefixes_seen[@]}"
```

...and read back into an identical data structure on the receiving end (should the receiving code be written in bash) like so:

```
declare -A prefixes_seen=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' prefix; do
  prefixes_seen[$prefix]=1
done
```

Comment: thank you for this (the provided reference as well). Will definitely study.