# how to make 'for in' not to split a string

Tags: string, bash, shell, split, find

I'm trying to rename several files. So I need those file names first.
I'm using:

```
for FILE in $(find . -type f -name "*.flv" -exec basename {} \; ); do
    echo "$FILE"
done
```

When I try just the find command, it returns the number of files correctly, but when Im using the for, I was expecting that ARQ would contain the entire name of a single file, but instead, it returns splited words of the filename.
So how can I get the entire name, not just separated words of it?

Comment: add a language tag  (bash script?)

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677546/bash-for-in-looping-on-null-delimited-string-variable). The answer there shows a loop over files found by find, separated by the null character (`-print0` option in find).

Comment: Just  `find . -type f -name "*.flv" -exec basename {} \;` already does what you want.

Comment: You might find [this article](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/), namely the section on "Setting IFS", informative.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to get that to work.  The simplest is to use find's `exec` fully:

```
find . -type f -name "*.flv" -exec bash -c 'f=$(basename "$1"); printf "%s\n" "$f"' _ {} \;
```

In other words, you can put complex scripts in the `-exec` clause if you like.

As a second choice, consider this loop:

```
find . -name '*.flv' -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' -r file
do 
   f=$(basename "$file")
   printf "%s\n" "$f"
done
```

Comment: Process substitution is an option `while read -r line; do f=$(basename "$line"); echo "$f"; done < <(find . -name '*.flv')`

Comment: That's a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) -- `basename` already prints its result to standard output; capturing it in a variable so you can `echo` that variable is just ... clumsy.

Comment: @tripleee If the goal of the OP was to echo file names, _then you would be absolutely correct_.  I think that, if you read the question carefully, it is clear that the basename-echo thing is merely a stand-in for a more complicated script that he intends to write (to rename files).  The question he asks here,though, is limited to how to handle file names with spaces.  I kept the two statements because they made it clear how a more complex script could be written using these techniques.

Comment: @John1024: your second attempt need GNU or BSD find and will fail with filename start with dash or contain escaped sequences. The use of `basename` is also useless, just using parameter expansion.

Comment: @cuonglm `find` will return file names with a path, so they will not start with a dash. Which escaped sequences would be a problem here, for example?  You mean escapes interpreted by (some dialects of) `echo`?

Comment: @tripleee: That's the `$f` in `echo "$f"`, it's result of `basename`. Yes, some `echo` implementation will be interpreted escape sequence. Example with `bash`, try `env BASHOPTS=xpg_echo bash -c 'echo "\0101"'`

Comment: @cuonglm Yes, you are right.  I often forget that `echo` has [so many problems](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).  Answer updated to use `printf`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `for` loop with the result from [Command Substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) without double quote causing the result to [break on space, tab and newline](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) by default (that's `IFS` default value).

POSIXly, you don't need anything other than `find` and an inline-script:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.flv" -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    printf "%s\n" "${f##*/}"
  done
' sh {} +
```

With GNU find, you don't need the inline-script:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.flv" -printf '%f\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the title of the question: avoiding splitting a string using for in:

Do not use the IFS field separators in the loop:

```
:~> a="sdad asd asda  ad
> fdvbdsvf
> dfvsdfv
> 4"

:~> for s in $a; do
       echo "== $s =="; 
    done
== sdad ==
== asd ==
== asda ==
== ad ==
== fdvbdsvf ==
== dfvsdfv ==
== 4 ==

:~> (IFS=; for s in $a; do
       echo "== $s =="; 
     done)
== sdad asd asda  ad
fdvbdsvf
dfvsdfv
4 ==
```

I used round brackets for the last command, so that the changed value of IFS is limited to that subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `find,` use `rename` command which is designed to rename multiple files.

For example:

```
rename 's/foo/bar/' **/*.flv
```

which would replace `foo` in filename into `bar` in all `*.flv` files recursively. If your shell supports [a new globbing option](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/globstar-new-bash-globbing-option) (such as Bash 4.x or zsh), make sure the option is enabled by `shopt -s globstar`.

Or if you're using `find` with a loop, you can use:

- `-print0` when piping to external programs such as `xargs` (with `-0`),
- use `-exec cmd` to run command directly on the file (`{}`)
- use `-execdir cmd` to execute command in the directory where the file is present