# bash “read -a” looping on null delimited string variable

Tags: arrays, bash, delimiter, null-character

I've been reading up on this post: [bash "for in" looping on null delimited string variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677546/bash-for-in-looping-on-null-delimited-string-variable)
to see if I would be able to handle arbitrary text containing spaces inside an array.

Based on the post above this works fine:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' myvar; do echo $myvar; done < <(find . -type f -print0)
```

To check my understanding I also did this (which still works fine):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' myvar; do echo $myvar; done < <(printf "%s\0" 'a b' 'c d')
```

However, then I attempt storing the output in an array it goes wrong:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' -a myvar < <(printf "%s\0" 'a b' 'c d')
```

The array holds only `a b` and not `c d`:

```
echo ${myvar[@]}
a b
```

Apparently, there is a finer detail I am missing here. Thanks for any help.

PS. I am running:

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Comment: From `help read`: *Read a line from the standard input and split it into fields.* 'a b\0c d` is more than a/one line.

Comment: `read -a` is for assigning words on a single line into an array. To read null-delimited lines into an array: `unset arr i; while IFS= read -r -d '' 'arr[i++]'; do :; done < <(printf "%s\0" 'a b' 'c d')`.

Comment: And a line is by definition terminated by ascii 0, right? Newline, for instance, is just a formatting character?

Comment: This use case makes me wonder why the `readarray` command doesn't allow you to specify an alternate line terminator.

Comment: I've implemented @4ae1e1's suggestion and it works fine. The compact syntax `read 'arr[i++]'; do :; done` was new to me. Thanks. I side effect was that I also learned the difference between:

Comment: ... I also realised that `arr1=(find *.*)` is not the same as `arr2=(*.*)`. The length of `arr1` is 1+ bigger than `arr2`.

Answer (score 13):

In `bash` 4.4, the `readarray` command gained a `-d` option analogous to the same option for `read`.

```
$ IFS= readarray -d '' myvar < <(printf "%s\0" 'a b' 'c d')
$ printf "%s\n" "${myvar[@]}"
a b
c d
```

If you must support earlier versions, you need to loop over the output explicitly.

```
while IFS= read -d '' line; do
    myvar+=( "$line" )
done < <(printf "%s\0" 'a b' 'c d')
```

Comment: Good to know `readarray` is finally getting `-d`. That's really a natural option to expect.

Comment: `myvar+=( "$line" )` splits on space character

Comment: @ToreH-W Not when `$line` is quoted.

Comment: I just learned another neat trick from this answer, which is that the `printf` command automatically loops as long as there are unused arguments remaining (and fabricates empty strings as arguments if there are not enough to fill the template).