# find's print0 option reimplementation in bash and awk (perl)

Tags: bash, printing, null, find, character

I have successfully written following function:

```
function print0(){
  stdin=$(cat);
  echo "$stdin" | awk 'BEGIN {ORS="\000";}; { print $0}';
}
```

which works as a `-print0` argument in `find` command, but basically for any command that passes it's output to this function. It is useful with `xargs -0`. Then I realized that also opposite of this function would be useful too. I have tried following:

```
function read0(){
  stdin=$(cat);
  echo "$stdin" | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\000"; ORS="\n";};  {print $0}';

  # EQUIVALENTS:
  # echo "$stdin" | perl -nle '@a=join("\n", split(/\000/, $_)); print "@a"'
  # echo "$stdin" | perl -nle '$\="\n"; @a=split(/\000/, $_); foreach (@a){print $_;}'
}
```

But it does not works, the interesting is that when I tried just commands (awk or perl) it worked like a charm:

```
# WORKING
ls | print0 | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\000"; ORS="\n";};  {print $0}'
ls | print0 | perl -nle '@a=join("\n", split(/\000/, $_)); print "@a"'
ls | print0 | perl -nle '$\="\n"; @a=split(/\000/, $_); foreach (@a){print $_;}'


# DOES NOT WORKING
ls | print0 | read0
```

What I am doing wrong? I am assuming that something is wrong with dealing null characters via following command: `stdin=$(cat);`

**EDIT:**
Thank you all, the conclusion is that bash variables cannot hold null value.
PS: mentioned command was just as example I know converting nulls to newlines and vice versa has not rational reason.

Comment: +1 Interesting. Can't help you though.

Comment: The shell uses C strings internally, and C uses `\0` as the string terminator. So you can't have that as a character in a string, it will just end it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers/comments mention, you can't put a null character in a bash string variable.  However if you can get rid of the variables and just handle the data in pipes/streams, then you can pass null characters through just fine:

```
function print0() {
  awk 'BEGIN {ORS="\000";}; {print $0}';
}

function read0() {
  awk 'BEGIN {RS="\000"; ORS="\n";};  {print $0}';
}
```

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/dir$ ls -1
file one
file_two
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/dir$ ls | print0 | read0
file one
file_two
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/dir$
```

Also using `ls` in this way is dangerous, because it won't work for filenames that contain newlines.  As far as I'm aware, `find` is **the** way to programmatically get a list of files in a directory, when odd characters appear in filenames.

---

**Update:**

Here's another way to programmatically get a list of files in a directory, when odd characters appear in filenames, without using `find` (or the flawed `ls`).  We can use a * glob to get the list of all files in the directory into a bash array.  Then we print out each member of the array, using 1 character of /dev/zero as a delimiter:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s dotglob    # display .files as well

dirarray=( * )

for ((i = 0 ; i < ${#dirarray[@]}; i++)); do
    [ "$i" != "0" ] && head -c1 /dev/zero
    printf "${dirarray[$i]}"
done
```

Comment: I think "\0" and "\000" ought to be identical on any awk -- at least, they are on the three awks I happen to have access to -- but setting `ORS` to `NUL`, regardless of how you do it, doesn't actually "work" on either `mawk` or the current version of the original awk code. What's `awk` on your system?

Comment: @rici - you're right -  "\0" and "\000" seem to be equivalent now - I must have been doing something wrong.  `awk` and `gawk` on my Ubuntu 12.04 are both "GNU Awk 3.1.8".

Comment: The array thing can be simplified to `printf "%s\0" "${dirarray[@]}"`. This prints a trailing null, but I think that's what you usually want. If all you want is simulate `find ... -print0`, you can do without the array and just say `printf "%s\0" *`.

Comment: @user2719058 - yes - very elegant!

Answer (score 3):

I would say that your implementation can be simplified as

```
function print0 { tr '\n' '\0'; }
function read0  { tr '\0' '\n'; }
```

which works as you want.

But, it adds no value; you just switch from new-line separated records to `NUL` separated records and vice-versa, while `find ... -print0` can handle multi-line filenames. Your idea doesn't solve that problem.

The practical view of your question - how can strings with embedded `NUL` characters be handled in bash - has been discussed on SO: [assign string containing null-character (\0) to a variable in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570531/assign-string-containing-null-character-0-to-a-variable-in-bash). The bottom line is, you have to escape them. Other than that, zsh supports embedded `NUL` characters, but apparently no other shell does.

There has been a [related discussion on bug-bash](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-11/msg00158.html) about the handling of `NUL` characters by the `read` shell builtin, which you may find interesting.