# read nul delimited fields

Tags: bash, nul

Given this file

```
printf 'alpha\0bravo\0charlie' > delta.txt
```

I would like to read the fields into separate variables. The reason I am using a
null separator is because the fields will contain file paths, which can contain
any character except null. I tried these commands:

```
IFS= read mike november oscar < delta.txt
IFS=$'\0' read mike november oscar < delta.txt
```

However the fields are not being properly split

```
$ echo $mike
alphabravocharlie
```

Comment: I don't believe that a file path contain any character except null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, I created this function

```
function read-nul {
  while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
  do
    read -d '' "$1"
    shift
  done
}
```

Example use

```
read-nul mike november oscar < delta.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

The assignment `IFS=$'\0'` doesn't make the null character a delimiter, since [Bash variables cannot hold null characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570531/assign-string-containing-null-character-0-to-a-variable-in-bash). `IFS=$'\0'` is equivalent to `IFS=`, which you can verify by doing:

```
bash-4.3$ IFS=$'\0'
bash-4.3$ echo ${#IFS}
0
```

And `IFS=` by definition means no word splitting at all (see [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting)).

What you can do is read the null delimited items one by one using the `-d` option of the [`read` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins). According to linked documentation,

> `-d delim`
>
> The first character of `delim` is used to terminate the input line, rather than newline.

We can use a null string for `delim` to get desired behavior.

Example (I took the liberty to add whitespace to your example to demonstrate how it achieves what to want — no splitting on whitespace):

```
bash-4.3$ printf 'alpha with whitespace\0bravo with whitespace\0charlie with whitespace' > delta.txt
bash-4.3$ { read -r -d '' mike; IFS= read -r -d '' november; IFS= read -r -d '' oscar; echo $mike; echo $november; echo $oscar; } < delta.txt
alpha with whitespace
bravo with whitespace
charlie with whitespace
```

I'm also using the `-r` option to preserve backslashes in the input file. Of course you can replace `< delta.txt` with a `cat delta.txt |` at the beginning.

I know reading one by one is annoying, but I can't think of anything better.

Comment: This is covered (among many other things) on http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 .