# Linux cat inline file with special characters

Tags: linux, cat

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat << EOF
A^@B^AC^B
EOF
```

Where:

- '^@' = decimal value 0
- '^A' = decimal value 1
- '^B' = decimal value 2

So, the file looks like this:

```
xxd main.sh
00000000: 2321 2f62 696e 2f62 6173 680a 0a63 6174  #!/bin/bash..cat
00000010: 203c 3c20 454f 460a 4100 4201 4302 0a45   << EOF.A.B.C..E
00000020: 4f46 0a                                  OF.
```

When I run the script, decimal values 0 and 1 seem to disappear:

```
./main.sh | xxd
00000000: 4142 4302 0a                             ABC..
```

My questions is why? I was expecting to have an output like this:

Character 'A', followed by decimal value 0, followed by 'B', followed by decimal value 1, followed by 'C', followed by decimal value 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking more about this issue, I realized that quoting the word/delimiter (as suggested by the other answer) should not affect the output of the script (parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion are not being performed in my script).

So, `\000` indeed disappears since you cannot use NULL character in either variable, or an argument of the command line.

But, `\001` disappears due to a bash bug. That value is used internally by bash as an escape character. The bug occurs in function `expand_word_internal` which does not properly handle that escape character (see bug report [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2018-04/msg00064.html)).

The bug is already fixed in the bash devel branch.

Answer (score 4):

The reason seems two-fold.

First, note you must **quote the word**/delimiter in the [here-document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents) **to avoid expansion(s)**:

> If *word* is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence \newline is ignored, and ‘\’ must be used to quote the characters ‘\’, ‘$’, and ‘`’.

So, if you write it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<"EOF"
A^@B^AC^B
EOF
```

you'll preserve all characters except NULL (`\0`).

But you can not use NULL char in either variable, or an **argument of the command line** (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570531/assign-string-containing-null-character-0-to-a-variable-in-bash)).

You *can use* NULLs in pipes/files though, so you might want to encode the content of your here-document and decode it on fly (for example with `xxd`).

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to use `echo -e` instead of `cat` to include null characters.

Comment: You can also (probably even better) use `printf` (eg. `printf '\0\01\xCA\xFE' | hd`). If you use `echo`, be sure to also add `-n`.