# How to use positional parameters with standard input in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm new to bash programming and struggling with this one portion of my program. I know how to use positional parameters in order to refer to certain elements of the command line, however, I can only get this to work if a file is specified. How can I use positional parameters with standard input like so:

```
  cat test_file | stats -r
```

In this instance, I can refer to stats with "$0" and -r with "$1" but how can I refer to the cat test_file part? For context, Stats is my program which finds the average and median of the numbers in test file. "-r' indicates that the program should read each row of the program. When the command line is written like this:

```
 stats -r test_file
```

I use this code to denote the -r

```
 if [[ "${1:0:2}" == '-r' ]]
     do stuff
```

Comment: _but how can I refer to the `cat test_file` part?_ Short answer: You can't!

Comment: If there is no positional argument (which you can tell by looking at `$#`), then you should just read from stdin. That will work with pipes as well as the case where the user wishes to type directly into the program.

Comment: How could I read from standard input if I needed to use it as an argument for a function ? So with the positional parameters i call the function like this: rows_stats $2  where $2 refers to the file name. How can I do the same with just standard input?

Comment: Oh I figured it out -- post below

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `stats -r "$(cat test_file)"`

Comment: Yes but this is for an assignment and the graders will explicitly try using "cat test_file  | stats - r " to see if the program works that way.

Answer (score -1):

Answer: As people stated you can't use positional parameters in this situation. The only alternative is to read from standard input and in my case store it in a variable to pass to a function.

Read here to learn more how to do that: [How to read mutliline input from stdin into variable and how to print one out in shell(sh,bash)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212965/how-to-read-mutliline-input-from-stdin-into-variable-and-how-to-print-one-out-in)

Comment: How does storing stdin into a variable help you pass it to a functing expecting a filename? (If you need to refer to stdin using a filename, it's `/dev/stdin`.)